# Heuristic algorithms to find the shortest path in a graph. Critique/improve my pseudo-code please

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

I have to implement two heuristic algorithms that are described below. Both algorithms try to find a shortest path from a given input node to node Z using heuristic approaches. In a shortest path, a node may appear at most once (i.e., a node cannot appear twice or more in a shortest path, but backtracking is allowed). Note that these two heuristic algorithms do not always have to find a correct shortest path.

Both algorithms should start with a given input node and iteratively determine the next node in a shortest path. In determining which node to choose as the next node, they use different heuristics.

Let w(n, v) be the weight of the edge between node n and node v. Let dd(v) be the direct distance from v to the destination node Z.

When choosing the next node from a current node n:

Algorithm 1: Among all nodes v that are adjacent to the node n, choose the one with the smallest dd(v).

Algorithm 2: Among all nodes v that are adjacent to the node n, choose the one for which w(n, v) + dd(v) is the smallest.

Z is reachable by all nodes.
All edge weights are positive integers.

I've got the graph loaded correctly but have had trouble implementing the algorithms, so I scrapped everything and went back to the drawing board.

Here is my pseudo-code, please let me know if I'm missing any cases or there is something else I need to consider. Efficiency is nice, but not necessary in this case. Any tip helps!

```
//----------    PSEUDOCODE ALGORITHM ONE   ----------//

    /*
    while currentNode != destination:
        add currentNode to visited list and set --> list to track total path, set to track shortest path
        for each node adjacent to currentNode:
            if adjacentNode has minimum direct distance to destination:
                get the connecting edge
                nextNode = adjacentNode --> nextNode = graph.opposite(currentNode, edgeToAdjacentNode)
                if nextNode is not in visited: --> list or set?
                    add edgeWeight to total distance traveled
                    add edgeWeight to shortest path distance
                    add nextNode to visited list and set
                    return find adjacentNode with minimum direct distance to destination (recurse on nextNode?)
                else (nextNode has already been visited, we are backtracking):
                    get the connecting edge from currentNode to nextNode
                    add edgeWeight to total distance traveled
                    remove the edge connecting adjacentNode to nextNode --> so we can't go back
                    remove key of nextNode from direct distance data structure --> so it's no longer shortest
                    return find adjacentNode with minimum direct distance to destination (recurse on currentNode?)
    */

    //----------    END PSUEDOCODE ALGORITHM ONE    ----------//

    //----------    PSEUDOCODE ALGORITHM TWO    ----------//

    /*
    while currentNode != destination:
        add currentNode to visited list and set --> list to track total path, set to track shortest path
        for each node adjacent to currentNode:
            calculate the sum of edgeWeight and direct distance to destination
        nextNode = adjacentNode with minimum sum
        if nextNode is not in visited (list or set?):
            add edgeWeight to total distance traveled
            add edgeWeight to shortest path distance
            add nextNode to visited list and set
            return recurse on nextNode?
        else:
            get the connecting edge from currentNode to nextNode
            add edgeWeight to total distance traveled
            remove the edge connecting adjacentNode to nextNode --> so we can't go back
            remove key of nextNode from direct distance data structure --> so it's no longer shortest
            return find adjacentNode with minimum direct distance to destination (recurse on currentNode?)
    */

    //----------    END PSUEDOCODE ALGORITHM TWO    ----------//
```

Output Example:

(A)  User enters node J as the start node

Algorithm 1:

Sequence of all nodes: J -> K ->  Z
Shortest path: J -> K ->  Z 
Shortest path length: 310

Algorithm 2:

Sequence of all nodes: J -> I -> L -> Z
Path: J -> I -> L -> Z 
Length: 278

(B) User enters node G as the start node

Algorithm 1:

Sequence of all nodes: G -> H -> T -> H -> L -> Z 
Shortest path: G -> H -> L -> Z 
Shortest path length: 359

Algorithm 2:

Sequence of all nodes: G -> H -> T -> H -> L -> Z
Shortest path: G -> H -> L -> Z 
Shortest path length: 359

Comment: Have a look at Dejkstra's Algorithm, which is looks like the second algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: what is the input of your given output? this seemed otherwise interesting

Comment: The input is just the starting node selected by the user

Comment: Or are you wondering what the graph looks like before the user selects a node?

Comment: Could I use Dijkstra's and put the direct distance value in instead of infinity?

Answer (score 0):

I got both of them working. Answering my own question just incase anyone else was interested in the solution. If you want to see the helper functions or other data structures I used just let me know. Cheers.

```
import accessories.*;
import accessories.Map;
import accessories.AdjacencyMapGraph.InnerVertex;

import java.util.*;
import static accessories.HelperFunctions.*;

public class project {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//----------    CREATION OF THE GRAPH AND DIRECT DISTANCE MAP  ----------//
    // create the adjacency matrix
    ArrayList<String[]> edgeList = readFile();
    // create empty graph
    AdjacencyMapGraph<String, Integer> graph = new AdjacencyMapGraph<>(true);

    //----------    UTILITY DATA STRUCTURES ----------//
    ArrayList<Vertex<String>> vertexListOne = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Vertex<String>> vertexSetOne = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Vertex<String>> deadEndsOne = new ArrayList<>();
    int shortestPathDistanceOne = 0;
    ArrayList<Vertex<String>> vertexListTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Vertex<String>> vertexSetTwo = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Vertex<String>> deadEndsTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    int shortestPathDistanceTwo = 0;


    // load the graph with Vertices and Edges
    graph = loadGraph(graph, edgeList);
    // create a HashMap of Vertices direct distance to destination
    Map<String, Integer> directDistMap = createDirectDistanceMap();


//----------    GET USER INPUT  ----------//
    // get the starting vertex
    Scanner selection = new Scanner(System.in);
    // prompt user
    System.out.println("Enter a node: ");
    String start = selection.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    // the destination Vertex
    Vertex<String> destination = setDestination(graph);

    // currentVertex is the current accessories.Vertex
    Vertex<String> currentVertex = getStartingVertex(graph, start);

    //----------    ALGORITHM ONE   ----------//
    Vertex<String> startVertex = currentVertex;
    while (!startVertex.equals(destination)) {
        // add startVertex to list and set
        vertexListOne.add(startVertex);
        vertexSetOne.add(startVertex);
        // for each adjacentVertex map the direct distance to the destination
        LinkedHashMap<Vertex<String>, Integer> adjVertDirDist = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Edge<Integer> outgoingEdge : graph.outgoingEdges(startVertex)) {
            Vertex<String> adjacentVertex = graph.opposite(startVertex, outgoingEdge);
            if (!deadEndsOne.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                int dd = directDistMap.get(adjacentVertex.getElement());
                adjVertDirDist.put(adjacentVertex, dd);
            }
        }
        // sort the adjVertDirDist by value and save it in a list
        List<java.util.Map.Entry<Vertex<String>, Integer>> list = sortMapByValue(adjVertDirDist);
        // first entry has vertex with closest direct distance to destination
        Vertex<String> nextVertex = list.get(0).getKey();
        // if nextNode is not in visited
        Edge<Integer> edge = graph.getEdge(startVertex, nextVertex);
        if (!vertexSetOne.contains(nextVertex)) {
            // add edgeWeight to shortestPathTraveled
            shortestPathDistanceOne += edge.getElement();
            startVertex = nextVertex;
            if (startVertex.equals(destination)) {
                // WE MADE IT!
                vertexListOne.add(startVertex);
                vertexSetOne.add(startVertex);
            }
        } else {
            // decrement shortest path distance
            shortestPathDistanceOne -= edge.getElement();
            // remove from set
            vertexSetOne.remove(startVertex);
            // mark dead end
            deadEndsOne.add(startVertex);
            // go to nextVertex (will be previous vertex)
            startVertex = nextVertex;
        }
    }

    displayResults(shortestPathDistanceOne, vertexListOne, vertexSetOne, 1);
    //----------    END ALGORITHM ONE   ----------//

    //----------    ALGORITHM TWO   ----------//

    Vertex<String> startVertexTwo = currentVertex;
    while (!startVertexTwo.equals(destination)) {
        // add startVertexTwo to list and set
        vertexListTwo.add(startVertexTwo);
        vertexSetTwo.add(startVertexTwo);
        // for each adjacentVertex map the direct distance to the destination
        LinkedHashMap<Vertex<String>, Integer> adjVertDirDist = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Edge<Integer> outgoingEdge : graph.outgoingEdges(startVertexTwo)) {
            Vertex<String> adjacentVertex = graph.opposite(startVertexTwo, outgoingEdge);
            if (!deadEndsTwo.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                int ddPlusWeight = outgoingEdge.getElement() + directDistMap.get(adjacentVertex.getElement());
                adjVertDirDist.put(adjacentVertex, ddPlusWeight);
            }
        }
        // sort the adjVertDirDist by value and save it in a list
        List<java.util.Map.Entry<Vertex<String>, Integer>> list = sortMapByValue(adjVertDirDist);
        // first entry has vertex with closest direct distance to destination
        Vertex<String> nextVertex = list.get(0).getKey();
        // if nextNode is not in visited
        Edge<Integer> edge = graph.getEdge(startVertexTwo, nextVertex);
        if (!vertexSetTwo.contains(nextVertex)) {
            // add edgeWeight to shortestPathTraveled
            shortestPathDistanceTwo += edge.getElement();
            startVertexTwo = nextVertex;
            if (startVertexTwo.equals(destination)) {
                // WE MADE IT!
                vertexListTwo.add(startVertexTwo);
                vertexSetTwo.add(startVertexTwo);
            }
        } else {
            // decrement shortest path distance
            shortestPathDistanceTwo -= edge.getElement();
            // remove from set
            vertexSetTwo.remove(startVertexTwo);
            // mark dead end
            deadEndsTwo.add(startVertexTwo);
            // go to nextVertex (will be previous vertex)
            startVertexTwo = nextVertex;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    displayResults(shortestPathDistanceTwo, vertexListTwo, vertexSetTwo, 2);

}   //----------    END MAIN    ----------//
```

}